# Running apps script in Google Sheet app

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to run google apps scripts I made on a google spreadsheet in the sheets app on my android tablet.

The app does not show me custom Ui menus I made and when I tap the button I made that is assigned a script, it simply selects the button instead of executing the script.

The Ui menu and buttons work just fine when I open the sheet from my PC.
So is it possible to run apps script on a spreadsheet from the sheets app?

Comment: See [Add a script trigger to Google Sheet that will work in Android mobile app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87346)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Android is concerned, These are the ways to run a apps script.

- Using the  `OnEdit`  trigger
- Using Custom Functions
- As far as custom menus are concerned, you need to create a separate  Android add ons (rather separate apps)